# Showing submenu to right in vertical menu bar

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I have following code, which shows vertical menu.

How can I place submenu to be populated on right?

```
<Menu Background="Transparent" Foreground="Honeydew">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit">
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<MenuItem Header="File">
    <MenuItem Header="File1">
        <MenuItem Header="SubMenu1">
            <MenuItem Header="SubSubMenu1" />
            <MenuItem Header="SubSubMenu1" />
        <MenuItem Header="SubMenu2"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="File1"></MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```